# Concatenate multiple fields on multiple rows with commas

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 2 tables connected by a join table. They look like the following

```
      servers             serverInstances          instances
| id |     ip     |     | id | sID | iID |       | id | name |
|____|____________|     |____|_____|_____|       |____|______|
| 11 | 10.0.0.100 |     |  1 |  11 |  40 |       | 40 | real |
| 12 | 10.0.0.200 |     |  2 |  11 |  41 |       | 41 | fake |
                        |  3 |  12 |  45 |       | 45 | test |
```

With the below query I can get the below data

```
SELECT s.ip, i.name
FROM servers AS s
JOIN serverInstances AS si ON s.ID = si.sID
JOIN Instances AS i ON si.iID = i.ID


|     ip     | name |
|____________|______|
| 10.0.0.100 | real |
| 10.0.0.100 | fake |
| 10.0.0.200 | test |
```

What I am having trouble with, is taking the above information, and writing a query that would return the following.

```
|     ip     | instances  |
|____________|____________|
| 10.0.0.100 | real, fake |
| 10.0.0.200 |    test    |
```

Is there an easy yet dynamic way to do write this query?

Comment: Look up the manual for `GROUP_CONCAT`

Comment: awesome. I will do that

Comment: @bwoebi You should post as the answer

Comment: @Orangepill wanted to give him only a hint, not the solution. People don't always need solutions.

Comment: I was able to make the solution myself! However if you post the solution i'll give it the checkmark

Comment: @bwoebi I'm at 510 for the day... you can have it

Comment: @Orangepill then you should have 525 today :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As bwoebi stated in comments group_concat will give you this.

```
SELECT s.ip,  group_concat(DISTINCT i.name ORDER BY i.name ASC SEPARATOR ", " ) as instances
FROM servers AS s
JOIN serverInstances AS si ON s.ID = si.sID
JOIN Instances AS i ON si.iID = i.ID 
GROUP BY s.ip;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you

```
SELECT s.ip, GROUP_CONCAT(i.name)
FROM servers AS s
JOIN serverInstances AS si ON s.ID = si.sID
JOIN Instances AS i ON si.iID = i.ID
GROUP BY s.ip
```